# id field not appending to div mvc 4

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc-4

I have a dialog that opens an items window. I want to select an item click `Add` have that item's id appended to a div where I can then submit it up to the db. I'm getting the id in the alert but nothing is appending. I want to append on the `Add` button click but was trying just on a click of the `li` which isn't working either.

Dialog options

```
   $('.ITA').dialog({
 autoOpen: false,
 draggable: true,
 width: 450,
 resizable: false,
 dialogClass: "ui-dialog",
 modal: true,
 show: { effect: 'fade', duration: 200 },
 buttons: [{
 id: "AddToAddPage",
 text: "Send Trade",
 click: function () {


  // on close the item selected is added to `div ITA`
  //$(this).dialog("close");

  });
```

get the `<li>` clicked and append to `div ITA`

```
  $(".ITA").on("click", "li", function () {
   //get div 
     var div = $("#DivToAddTo");   

   //get id of item
    var itemtoadd = $(this).attr("data-id");    

    alert(itemtoadd);//for debug

    //apendTo?
    $(itemtoadd).appendTo(div); 
   });
```

The view where selected items should go

```
@model IEnumerable<Item>

@{
ViewBag.Title = "Tradepage";
}
<div id="Item">

 @foreach (var item in Model)
 { 
<ul>
    <li>
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.ID)
    </li>
     <li>
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.item_name)
    </li>
    <li>
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.item_description)
    </li>
</ul>

 }
 </div>
 <div id="AddNav">
  <a class="AllItemsBtn" href='@Url.Action("GetItemsToAdd")' >Add File...</a>
  <a class="SubmitAdds" href="#" >Submit</a>
    </div>

 <div class = "ITA"></div>

 <div id = "AddedItems">Added items go here</div>
```

View where items are

```
@foreach (var item in Model)
 { 
<ul>
    <li data-id = "@item.ID">
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.ID)
    </li>
     <li>
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.item_name)
    </li>
    <li>
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.item_description)
    </li>
  </ul>
 }

 <div id="addItemBtn">
<button id="AddToAPage">Add</button>

 <p><a id="AddToAdd" href="#">Add</a></p>
 </div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace

```
$(itemtoadd).appendTo(div);
```

With:

```
div.text(itemtoadd);
```

That should update the contents of the div with the selected id.  Here is a simple example:  [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rekXc/) . Click on one of the list items to see the id updated.

Comment: That did it. Can i also just add this code to  the button click and on close have it update the div?

Comment: Yes.  You can also add that code to the Dialog's Add button.  You will have to change how you get the id of the <li/> `var itemtoadd = $(this).attr("data-id");` because "this" refers to a different element.